# Find $a,b,c \in \mathbb {Q}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Find $a,b,c \in \mathbb {Q}$ such that:
$\left\{\begin{array}{rl} x^3&\in \mathbb Q \\ x&\notin \mathbb{Q}\\ ax^2+bx+c &=0\end{array}\right.$

I tried Vieta's formulas, but seem like it didn't help.

I think $a=b=c=0$ is only solution.

Comment: It's not clear (to me) if you allow $x$ to be complex. Does $x\notin\mathbb{Q}$ mean $x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$a^2x^3=-ax(bx+c)=-b(ax^2)-cax=b(bx+c)-cax=x(b^2-ac)+bc$$

$$x^3=\frac{x(b^2-ac)+bc}{a^2}$$ will be $\in Q$ iff $x$ $\in Q$ unless $b^2-ac=0$

If $b^2=ac, \frac cb=\frac ba=r$(say) $\implies b=ar,c=br=ar^2$

$\implies  ax^2+bx+c=a(x^2+rx+r^2)=0\implies x^2+rx+r^2=0$ as $a\ne0$

$\implies x=r\frac{-1\pm\sqrt3i}2$ which is not $\in Q$ for $r\in Q$

But $x^3=r^3$ which  $\in Q$ for $r\in Q$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** A nice, simple rational number to start your investigations with is $1$. Maybe for simplicity, try assuming that $x^3=1$. Maybe one of $a$, $b$, or $c$ could be $1$. Experiment and see what happens!

Answer (score 3):

Take a primitive cube root of $1$. Then $x^3 = 1$, $x\notin\mathbb{R}$ and $x^2+x+1 = 0$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hints:**

Do you know about cube roots of unity? There are two other cube roots of $1$ other than $1$ which are imaginary. Those are $e^{i2\pi/3}$ and $e^{i4 \pi/3}$. You have sufficient conditions now. Good luck.

Comment: Did you mean $e^{i2\pi/3}$?